# npm start does not work. I've tried everything. I'm confused

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

So whenever I run **npm start** in my *React* project it gives me this error:

> myapp@0.1.0 start C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\React\myapp  react-scripts
>   start
>
> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.19.1"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules\webpack (version: 3.10.0)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an
>   .env file in your project. That will permanently disable this message
>   but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
>   We hope you find them helpful!
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start:
>   `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the myapp@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\AyaLe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-02T10_15_24_630Z-debug.log

**Also whenever I try to install webpack-cli whenever it asks me to, it gives me another error**

Comment: Please include `npm` and `node` versions. Maybe a silly question: did you run `npm install`? A lot of the steps you mentioned are unnecessary. E.g.: 'Remove package-lock.json' because as longs as you do not use `npm ci` to install dependencies this file is ignored.

Comment: I've used the create-react-app so that should've taken care installing all the dependencies. This is the package.json :

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}

Comment: You may need to manually delete C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules. By default npm will search parent folders for node_modules which isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have `"webpack": "3.10.0"` installed globally, but you need to have `"webpack": "4.19.1"`. This is causing a conflict.

You need to do the following:

```
1. $npm uninstall -g webpack
2. $npm install -g webpack@4.19.1
```

This should solve the issue.

Alternatively, you can try deleting the `node_modules` folder or specifically the `webpack` folder in `node_modules` at the location:

> C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules\webpack (version: 3.10.0)

Comment: This will work if the path mentioned in the OP (C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules) is the global node_modules folder, but I thought it was in a different location by default on Windows... (I'm on Mac though, so I'm not sure)

Comment: The conflict is because of the different version of the webpack in this location ((C:\Users\AyaLe\node_modules). If you are using CRA, you need webpack version 4.19.1. So, either you need to update your webpack version globally or prune the webpack in the node_modules folder mentioned in the location by either deleting the entire node_nodules folder (can cause some issues if you have global dependencies) or specifically removing webpack from the folder.

Comment: I assume you meant to say "specifically removing webpack from the folder"

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo @MattBrowne

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an incorrect version of 'webpack' installed. Check your `package.json` file to ensure that you have the correct 'webpack' version.

The file should look like something this :

```
{ 
    ... , 
    "dependencies" : { 
        ..., 
        "webpack" : "<version number>" 
    } 
}
```

Ensure that the version number is exactly `4.19.1`. This will ensure that you install the specific version of webback.

Once you change/update your `package.json`, try deleting `node_modules/` directory and then running `npm install` in the same directory as your `package.json` is.

Comment: Actually there's no webpack in the package.json. Only react, react-dom, and react-scripts. I've used the create-react-app command, that should've taken care of the full installation so I don't know why I'm not seeing the webpack dependency

Comment: Webpack is a dependency of react-scripts